# Make "cel" tag synonym of "common-expression-language"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I believe that tag [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cel) is an abbreviation for [common-expression-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-expression-language) and therefore I think that tag "cel" should be made a synonym (or should I say "tag alias"?) for tag "common-expression-language". I don't meet the criteria for suggesting a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cel/synonyms) for this tag. I discovered the tag because I think it was incorrectly added to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75252693/how-do-i-highlight-multiple-jtable-cells-one-by-one-then-unhighlight-them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct the [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cel) tag was added incorrectly to [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75252693/15497888) (it has now been removed). That question was about cell highlighting, so the asker was probably trying for [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell) and missed a letter.

In general, [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cel) seems like a poor tag name, given that it is so close to the word cell *and* that such a short acronym could represent any number of things.

For this reason, I've merged [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cel) into [common-expression-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-expression-language) which now has 4 questions total, but I have not created the synonym. It's better that the tag be removed from the system.

Comment: E.g., [CEL token cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEL) (whatever that is). For [Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius_(disambiguation))?